# Create Tags failing with error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nosuchmethoderror, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am able to create instances using aws-sdk-java, but recently when trying to create tags for naming the instances I am repeatedly getting the error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2.createTags(Lcom/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateTagsRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateTagsResult;

```
            Tag resourceName = new Tag("Name", instanceName);
            List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
            tags.add(resourceName);
            CreateTagsRequest tag_request = new CreateTagsRequest()
                    .withTags(resourceName).withResources("i-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            try {
                CreateTagsResult tag_response = ec2Client.createTags(tag_request);
            }catch(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried setting tag name while creating the instance using

```
        List<TagSpecification> tagSpecifications = new ArrayList<>();
        tagSpecifications.add(new TagSpecification().withTags(tags));
        runInstancesRequest.withTagSpecifications(tagSpecifications);
```

But even that is failing with same error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. While compilation there is no issue, then I do not understand why there is this error after deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the method name createTags does not exist within the class AmazonEC2 or you pass a wrong parameter list to the method.

This can also happen if the client and server side version of the aws-sdk-java api differ from each other. Be sure that you use the correct client side API.

The AmazonE2Client is mostly deprecated: 
@see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html

The documentation says "use AWSClientBuilder instead"

Comment: I have added 1.11.333 version of aws-sdk-java as a library on my client side. It is the latest version as shown by eclipse.

Comment: Yeah you pointed out correctly, the issue was with client and server side versions of sdk. I had to convert the project to maven and then use 1.11.335 version since as a library the last version was listing as 1.11.333. Cheers!!